# how to find selected rowcellvalue in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, grid, row

i'm trying to delete a record in my gridview. for doing this i added a button field in to gridview.Then i give a command name to button filed. and i wrote codes like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {

        try
        {

            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "Delete from Table where id='" + SelectedRowAndCellValue +"'"

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();

            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

but i cant find SelectedRowAndCellValue. thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with this code

```
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
  var result = row.Cells[yourIndex].Text;

  cmd.CommandText = "Delete from Table where id = "+row.Cells[yourIndex].Text;
```

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "Delete from Table where id=+row.Cells[yourIndex].Text;